# detect file changes in vagrant guest machine

Tags: javascript, vagrant, nfs, gulp-watch, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm using Vagrant 1.8.4, running Ubuntu 14.04 box. I have installed node v6.2.2 and I'm running windows 10 x64-bit on the host machine, when I change js files and run gulp watch / babel script.js --watch --out-file compiled.js 
The problem the changes are not detected by the guest machine.

I tried the following but no luck:

```
 config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www",          
     :nfs => true,                                 
     :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666", "lookupcache=none"]  

and this
     :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666", "actimeo=1"]
```

Please advice,

Answer (score 7):

So I was running into this same problem with Vagrant and an `Angular 4` + `Angular CLI` project. While running the development server, file changes weren't triggering a rebuild of the files and a reload of the app. The issue is that file system events aren't forwarded to the Vagrant virtual machine. Installing the `vagrant-notification-forwarder` vagrant plugin solved the problem for me:

- https://github.com/mhallin/vagrant-notify-forwarder

Answer (score 2):

The above mentioned solution "vagrant-notify-forwarder" not reliable for me. Sometimes it doesn't work for mac.

"vagrant-fsnotify" plugin works for me.

Read here for configuration setup
https://github.com/adrienkohlbecker/vagrant-fsnotify